# To download files in different format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple files and multiple file formats(.SHP,.KML,.CSV),all this format files are stored in particulate folder.I want select file from selection box and also select format for that file and then click on download button so file get downloaded.How to do code for this in JS or jQuery.
Thank You

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service. Did you try anything and fail?

Comment: We are here to give tips on how to fix your code, not write it for you. We need to see some effort on your part.

Comment: I tried but i am able to download only one file in one format.

Comment: Here is my code  <form name="George">
<p><select name="example" size="1" onChange="go()">
<option value="http://176.9.117.220:8080/geoserver/Bank/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Bank:1975-1990_builtup&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=SHAPE-ZIP">Cnet</option>

Comment: <option value="http://www.cnn.com">CNN</option>
<option value="http://www.geocities.com">Geocities</option>
</select></p>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
function go(){
location=
document.George.example.
options[document.George.example.selectedIndex].value
}
</script>
 <input type="button" name="test" value="Go!" onClick="go()">
</form>

Comment: I am unable to post all code at a time,please check code in 2 comments.

Comment: Is there any tips or link which help me to do this?

Comment: update your question not your comments.